# Create email report from Airflow data profiling section

Tags: airflow

I'm using a bit of airflow recently and now my dags are up and running I've looked at some data in the data profiling section of the UI.
Made some charts, some table full of data.
I would like to be able to send me once a week those chart and data in an email so I can have some regular global update about my different dag runs and tasks, not just an email in the end of each run saying success or fail.

Is there any convenient way of doing that ? or do I have to build a custom dag with jinja template email operator and horrible SQLAlchemy syntax to re-extract data from the database ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found some kind of solution. Feel free to comment on the way I do things if there's better way of doing it. I would be glad to here

I've created a static function to recover data from a chart:

```py
from airflow import settings

def get_data_profilling_data( chart_label):
    """
    Get an array containing data from a data profilling chart.

    Args: 
        chart_label: a string that is the name of a an available chart in Data Profiling section.
        session(None, optional): Not in use.
    Returns:
        A list of tuple with first element representing the header of column.
    """
    import logging
    query_filters = [models.Chart.label == chart_label]
    session = settings.Session()
    # Query database to get a chart object.
    chart_object = session.query(models.Chart).filter(*query_filters).first()

    # Replace useless caracter in query and replace % by %% so it's not interpreted by SQLAlchemy
    # Also add a ; at the end of the statement.
    sql="{}{}".format(chart_object.sql.replace('\n', ' ').replace('\r',' ').replace('%','%%'), ';')

    query = session.connection().engine.execute(sql)
    #recover sql request header.
    headers = tuple(query.keys())
    #recover all data
    data  = query.fetchall()
    #close database connection
    #session.connection().close()
    # Add headers to first position in the list
    data.insert(0,headers)
    return data
```

Once this is extracted I've used jinja templating :

```py
    jinja_str = """<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
        {% if title %}
            <title>{{ title }}</title>
        {% else %}
            <title>Airflow reports</title>
        {% endif %}
        </head>
        <body>
        <table>
        {% if rows %}
            {% for row in rows %}
                {% if loop.index == 1 %}
                    <!-- table header -->
                    <tr>{% for elem in row %}
                            <th>{{ elem }}</th>
                        {% endfor %}</tr>
                {% endif %}
                {% if loop.index > 1 %}
                    <tr>{% for elem in row %}
                        <td>{{ elem }}</td>
                    {% endfor %}</tr>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
        </table>
        </body>
    </html>"""

    def format_data_from_chart(chart, **kwargs):
        data = DagStatic.get_data_profilling_data(chart)
        report_template = Template( jinja_str )
        report_html = report_template.render({"title": chart,"rows":data})
        kwargs["ti"].xcom_push(key='report_html', value=report_html)
```

This would push into xcom the result of the data from chart rendered with jinja template.
I can now use Email Operator to send my mail:

```py
    send_report= email_task = EmailOperator(
                                            to='you.mail@mail.com',
                                            task_id='send_report',
                                            subject='Airflow HTML report start_date {{ ds }}',
                                            html_content="{{  ti.xcom_pull(key='report_html') }}",
                                            dag=dag)
```

Hope this will help you. Feel free to comment on the way I do things if there's better way of doing it. I would be glad to here

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge there's nothing "out of the box" that will do what you want; you're likely correct on the "I have to build a custom dag […]" part of your question. Luckily since you're *in* Airflow, you can leverage its codebase to help:

```py
from airflow import models, settings


def python_task(**context):
    chart_label = context.params["chart_label"]
    query_filters = [models.Chart.label == chart_label]

    session = settings.Session()
    chart_object = session.query(models.Chart).filter(*query_filters).first()

    [...] build and send the email [...]
```

You will likely want to look at the Airflow source code, specifically the email handling portions and interface rendering. Note that if you can make your task relatively abstract you can reuse it pretty easily.

Comment: Hello are you saying that in this case `"chart_label"`  could be a filter to select an existing request I build in `data profilling` section ?

Comment: Yep, although you'll want to double check the specifics of the model (`models.Chart` I believe it is) for your version of Airflow. Then I would put a parameter on the DAG that corresponds to the chart you want to render and email.

Comment: That's amazing, I didn't know I could that. I'm really terrible at Python in general I find it very confusing and tend to stay away from it as much as possible. I'll try your code and maybe post my own answer with more complete example. Thanks for the tips :-)

Comment: So far I don't know why but the only thing it return is an object of type `airflow.models.chart.Chart` but I'm absolutly unable to extract data from it. I can't even get the sql statement available to execute because it's not properly formatted. :-( but still this is an interesting thing to look at.

Comment: Thank you @joebeeson I posted my solution. It does work in the end, but it's only because of you.